# How do I list all directories with include same name subdirectory?

Tags: linux, command-line, find, list

My musiclibrary is a mess.

I try to create this structure:

> /music

> /music/artist/album/

For some reason I have several artist with this structure.

> /music

> /music/artist/artist/

> /music/artist/artist/album/

How can I find every artist-directory from '/mymusic' that include same name sub-directory '/mymusic/artist/artist' so I can fix structure manually.

Than you.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and use the same directory name `/music` or `mymusic` in all places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a `find` command, this example should scan all the music contents:

```
find /music -mindepth 1 -print
```

Adding `awk` command to filter each component of the path (splitting on "/" as a separator) and checking where the last and second last component match will tell you when you have duplicated a directory and subdirectory names:

```
find /music -mindepth 1 -print | awk -F"/" '{ if ($NF == $(NF-1)) { print }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The command below loops over all subdirectory names, checks if a nested subdirectory of the same name exists and shows the command to move the contents one directory up and to remuve the nested subdirectory.

```
cd /music
for i in */
do
    if [ -d "$i/$i" ]
    then
       echo mv "$i/$i"/* "$i"/.
       echo rmdir "$i/$i"
    fi
done
```

If this is what you need, repeat the command with the `echo` before `mv` and `rmdir` removed.

Note that the commands will contain double `/`, e.g. `artist//artist//album` but this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `find`:

```
find /music -type d -execdir test -d {}/{} \; -print
```

For each file of the type directory `test` will be run. The trick is in how `-execdir` differs from `-exec`: for a directory named `something`, `test` will be run in its *parent directory* and `{}` will be expanded to `./something`. In effect the actual inside command will be `test -d ./something/./something`, equivalent to `test -d something/something`. Then we use the fact that `-execdir … \;` (like `-exec … \;`) is not only an action, it is a test that succeeds iff the exit status from whatever it runs is 0. `test -d` checks if the given pathname is the name of a directory, it reports success via its exit status.

This way `-print` will be evaluated only (almost only, see just below) for directories containing directories of the same name.

Notes:

1. `test -d` succeeds also for a symlink to a directory. You can add `! -execdir test -L {}/{} \;` (before `-print`) to ignore cases where `something/something` is a symlink.
2. In general remember that `{}` expands to what `find` considers the pathname of the currently processed file, not necessarily to what a command like `realpath …` would print. Similarly `-name` tests what `find` considers the name, not necessarily to what `basename "$(realpath …)"` would print. E.g. if the starting point is `/music` then at some point our command will test `./music/./music` inside `/music/..`, so effectively `/music/music` which may or may not be an existing directory and the test is conclusive, which is fine. But:

   - If the (or a) starting point was `.` (or e.g. `/music/.`!), then it would be reported because `test -d` would test `./././.` which is a directory for sure (regardless of the working directory of `test`), so the test is not conclusive. `! -name .` is a test that "fixes" this, i.e. it unconditionally excludes `.`. But now we can miss a directory: if the current working directory is `/music` and `/music/music` exists, we won't detect it.

     In general passing `.` as a starting point to `find` is quite common. In our case, if you need to start at `.`, consider `find "$PWD" …` instead.
   - Similarly if the (or a) starting point was `..` (or e.g. `/music/artist/..`), then it would be reported because `test -d` would test `./.././..` which is a directory for sure (regardless of the working directory of `test`). `! -name ..` is a test that "fixes" this, but again we can miss one specific directory. In general passing `..` as a starting point to `find` is uncommon, still possible.

   If the starting point is `/music` then there will be no problem.
3. The successful detection occurs when `find` processes the upper (closer to `/`) directory from each `something/something` pair, not the lower one. This has the following consequences:

   - Our command will print paths like `/music/foo/bar/something` (as opposed to `/music/foo/bar/something/something`)
   - For `-mindepth` or `-maxdepth` (if you decide to use them), the depth of the upper directory matters.
   - If you want to automate doing something to one of the directories of the pair:

     - work with the upper one by passing `{}` after `-exec` or `-execdir`;
     - but the easiest way to address the lower one is to use `{}/{}` after `-execdir` like we did; in general this will *not* work after `-exec`.